# Group visibility doesnt toggle inside visibility?

Tags: groups

how come turnign off visibility on a group doesnt turn off visbility for the things inside it?
This happens often and is really annoying

Comment: it does, but maybe your object is part of several collections?

Comment: Perhaps they consider it useless,as collection icon already does it.